# SQL query to select values for a current or specific month in a given date/time format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have  saved the date in the database (mysql) as  `(d-m-Y  H:i:s)`

How can  write a sql query to select all the values that are only for the current month or a specific month ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%m-%Y') = '07-2012';
```

Answer (score 3):

Store your dates in MySQL DATE format and use the following query:

```
SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        table 
    WHERE 
        MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND 
        YEAR(date_field) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Storing dates as a string/varchar is a very bad idea.

Comment: Even better is to make the comparison on the bare date column and keep the query sargable (i.e. able to utilize indexes): `WHERE date_field >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE MONTH(`your_date_column`)=6 
AND YEAR(`your_date_column`)=2012
```

Gets everything from June 2012.